# Replace library autoload source in Laravel using composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel project that uses this library `BeyondCode\\LaravelWebSockets`

It was installed like that:
`composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets`

But I had to modify it so I've made a copy and set the autoload to point to my modified copy:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
    "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
    "BeyondCode\\LaravelWebSockets\\": "packages/laravel-websockets"
  }
},
```

Somehow it works on my local environment but when I try to run `composer install` or `composer dump-autoload` on production the new files are skipped because the location doesn't match the PSR-4 standart.

This way the paths described in `./vendor/composer/autoload_static.php` and `./vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` keep on pointing to the original library.

Is there a way to ignore PSR-4 requirement for this specific library?

Comment: What do you mean by "I had to modify it"? If you don't want to use the code provided by that library, remove it from your `composer.json`. Why not properly use the library and extend it through the common ways of the service container (as in: extending or decorating a service)?

Comment: Unfortunately the type of the changes don't allow me to easely extend it.

Comment: You are doing this wrong. You need to define a custom local repository with your local copy/fork.